# How to be navigated to the page of the profile details when the user's name is clicked

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-web

Hello so I created a fake data in Mockaroo to display the users and its profile details. My goal here is to display the names and when clicked it will redirect to the profile details.

So far here is my code. I would really appreciate your help since I'm very new to this.

```
Future<List<Users>> _getUsers() async {
    var data =
        await http.get("https://my.api.mockaroo.com/users.json?key=8f9261404");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Users> users = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      Users user = Users(
          u["user_id"],
          u["name"],
          u["email"],
          u["mobile"],
          u["address"]);

      users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
  }
```

I made a class

```
class Users {
  Users(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.email,
      this.mobile,
      this.address});

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String mobile;
  final String address;
 
}
```

This is my UI

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _getUsers(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      key: Key("$index"),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),);
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
```

Again, my goal here is to be navigated to the page of the profile details when the user's name is clicked.

Comment: Just wrap ur ListTile’s title with GestureDetector and do

Comment: Hello can you please elaborate more? And I also don't think I will use GestureDetector. I'm looking for something like navigator.of.push but I'm confused how to do it since the data needs to display the correct details of each user when a certain name is clicked.

Comment: Have u created profile details page?

Comment: hello yes I did but my problem is when I try to put `Text("Mobile No.: ${userData.mobile}")` there is an error because $userData is initialized in this page where I pasted my code above. How can I use $userData in profile details page?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `ListTile` with an `GestureDetector` and then use `Navigator`, like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: ListTile(
            key: Key("$index"),
            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
    onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return DetailScreen(data: snapshot.data.documents[index]);
            }),
    },
)
```

Inside `onPressed` you navigate to your detail screen and you pass your data to your detail screen. This is done by passing the data as parameter to your detail screen: `return DetailScreen(data: snapshot.data.documents[index]);`. You can then access your data in your new detail screen using the `data` parameter.
You have to create your detail screen at first, like this:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

final DocumentSnapshot data;
  
  DetailScreen({this.data})

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //Do something with data
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! 

I have a question Sir. Where does this ``data`` in ``return DetailScreen(data: snapshot.data[index])`` declared?

Comment: You have to declare it in your details screen. That means you have to create a new Class (a new Screen). There you can declare `data` as well everything else you wan't to see on your screen. I've given an example above.